# Case-insensitive getattr

Tags: python-3.x

Given a module I want to be able to search for classes in that module with case insensitivity.

For example if I have the following module `utils/helpers.py`

```
class UtilityClass:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

In a different script, I want to be able to retrieve the class by its name in a case insensitive way

```
import utils.helpers as util_helpers

module = getattr(util_helpers, 'utilityclass')
```

What is the right and most Pythonic way to implement this?

Comment: what if there are `UtilityClass` and `utilityClass`? this should return a `list`, raise an exception or what?

Comment: naive non-efficient kludge is something like: `whatever = {k.lower(): v for k, v in vars(util_helpers).items()}['utilityclass']` - but is there any reason you want to do this and have you considered what'd happen if there were multiple names that matched?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov you can assume that will never happen for my case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override `builtins.getattr` with a case-insensitive version:

```
import builtins
import pprint
def igetattr(obj, attr):
    for a in dir(obj):
        if a.lower() == attr.lower():
            return orig_getattr(obj, a)
orig_getattr = builtins.getattr
builtins.getattr = igetattr
print(getattr(pprint, 'prettyprinter'))
```

This outputs: `<class 'pprint.PrettyPrinter'>`

Comment: This doesn't work. In my case I'm not looking for variable inside a class, but a class inside a module. when I run `dir(util_helpers)` the class name does not come back

Comment: It actually should work. I've updated my answer with an example of getting a class inside a module with a case-insensitive name. Please update your question with your actual code if you still can't get it to work for you.

Comment: I get TypeError: igetattr takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given when I try to use this. Specifically when I try `builtins.getattr = igetattr`

Comment: @Shawn Can you post your code at repl.it so we can see how the error is produced?